# ElGamal signature scheme problem and unsure whether my calculations are wrong or that's the answer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Trying to solve problem with verifying a message through the ElGamal signature scheme and I end up getting two different values.

I'm given a prime number $p = 881$, $e_1 = 3 d = 60$, random value $r =  11$. I have to

a) Find $e_2$ and the signature of the message $M = 300$.

b) Verify the signature.

I'm stuck on part $b$. Verifying $V_1$ and $V_2$ I get two different answers and I'm unsure whether I'm doing the calculations wrong or if that's the answer.

[Here's the diagram showing the formulas for each calculation along the ElGamal signature process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVVET.png)

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) instead. You'll likely get better and faster answers there.

Comment: The diagram says we need $(r, p-1) = 1$, but there's something fishy with $881$ and $11$...